# Nested using statements in C#

Tags: c#, .net, file, using

I am working on a project. I have to compare the contents of two files and see if they match each other precisely.

Before a lot of error-checking and validation, my first draft is:

```
  DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\TestArea\\");
  FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles(filename + ".*");

  FileInfo outputFile = files.Where(f => f.Extension == ".out").Single<FileInfo>();
  FileInfo expectedFile = files.Where(f => f.Extension == ".exp").Single <FileInfo>();

  using (StreamReader outFile = new StreamReader(outputFile.OpenRead()))
  {
    using (StreamReader expFile = new StreamReader(expectedFile.OpenRead()))
    {
      while (!(outFile.EndOfStream || expFile.EndOfStream))
      {
        if (outFile.ReadLine() != expFile.ReadLine())
        {
          return false;
        }
      }
      return (outFile.EndOfStream && expFile.EndOfStream);
    }
  }
```

It seems a little odd to have nested `using` statements.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I think I may have found a syntactically cleaner way of declaring this using statement, and it appears to work for me? using var as your type in the using statement instead of IDisposable seems to allow me to instantiate both of my objects and call their properties and methods of the class they are allocated with, as in using(var uow = UnitOfWorkType1(), uow2 = UnitOfWorkType2()){}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dealing with nested "using" statements in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217734/dealing-with-nested-using-statements-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @200_success This question was asked in 2009 and that one in 2013, so I would probably flip the duplication identification if anything. (2¢, fyi, etc)

Answer (score 630, accepted):

The preferred way to do this is to only put an opening brace `{` after the last `using` statement, like this:

```
using (StreamReader outFile = new StreamReader(outputFile.OpenRead()))
using (StreamReader expFile = new StreamReader(expectedFile.OpenRead())) 
{
    ///...
}
```

Comment: Wow I learned something today. You can use this approach with different type. +1

Comment: Yeah that approach is nice when the types are different.

Comment: Cleaner? and also doesn't force you to use the same types.. I always do it this way even if the types match for readability and consistency.

Comment: even if your going to trim out the brackets, for sake of convention I recommend you keep the indent on the nested portion

Comment: @Hardryv: Visual Studio's auto-format removes it.  The idea is to look like a list of variable declarations.

Comment: Not sure if I find that more readable at all. If anything it breaks the look of nested code. And it looks as if the first using statement is empty and unused. But, I guess what ever works... :/

Comment: @Bryan Watts, the "contrarians" may be expressing real preferences. It's very likely that a different group of devs would've dissented had nesting been recommended. The only way to know is to run the experiment again in a parallel universe.

Comment: CAVEAT: This does not work when passing a stream object to the StreamReader, because the StreamReader will dispose the stream as well ! See http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms182334.aspx

Comment: @fmuecke: That's not very true; it will work.  The rules for `IDisposable` state that calling `Dispose()` twice should do nothing.  That rule is only in case of poorly-written disposables.

Comment: Perfect! Is this by design? The fact that visual studio's auto-format removes the nesting tells me that it is.

Comment: @ConnellWatkins: You can do the same thing with `if`, `for`, or `while`, except that it will indent.  Specifically, you can use a single statement instead of a block, and `using` is a single statement.

Comment: @SLaks, yes I am well aware of this (hence I'm asking, because of the difference in the way visual studio nests them). Anyway that is not true for all code blocks.. what about `try`, `catch` and `finally`?

Comment: @ConnellWatkins: Those require braces.  http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/04/why-are-braces-required/

Comment: @SLaks Jesus Christ. Yes I know.. Rhetorical question to point out that you can't use a single statement in place of any old block (as you said). Let me rephrase - Do we think multiple using statements were **supposed** to be written like this as per a design decision by someone in the C# team at Microsoft? Visual Studio's different approach to nesting these would indicate that that is true.

Comment: @ConnellWatkins: I strongly assume so, unless you think that the editor feature happened entirely by accident

Comment: Nope. I've made the same assumption (as I've said twice already). I'm after some proof or documentation, not just assumptions really. No worries, thanks anyway.

Comment: With this I would have to suppress the SA1503 rule of stylecop

Answer (score 152):

If the objects are of the **same type** you can do the following

```
using (StreamReader outFile = new StreamReader(outputFile.OpenRead()), 
                    expFile = new StreamReader(expectedFile.OpenRead()))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Well they are all the same type if they are all IDisposable perhaps a cast would work?

Comment: @jpierson that does work, yes, but then when you're calling the `IDisposable` objects from inside the using block, we can't call any of the class members (without a cast, which defeats the point imo).

Comment: IDisposable is a type so just use it as the type to have a list of mixed types, as seen in a few other answers.

Answer (score 39):

When the `IDisposable`s are of the same type, you can do the following:

```
 using (StreamReader outFile = new StreamReader(outputFile.OpenRead()), 
     expFile = new StreamReader(expectedFile.OpenRead()) {
     // ...
 }
```

The MSDN page on [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) has documentation on this language feature.

You can do the following whether or not the `IDisposable`s are of the same type:

```
using (StreamReader outFile = new StreamReader(outputFile.OpenRead()))
using (StreamWriter anotherFile = new StreamReader(anotherFile.OpenRead()))
{ 
     // ...
}
```

Answer (score 28):

Since [C# 8.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#using-declarations) you can use a *using declaration*.

```
using var outFile = new StreamReader(outputFile.OpenRead());
using var expFile = new StreamReader(expectedFile.OpenRead());
while (!(outFile.EndOfStream || expFile.EndOfStream))
{
    if (outFile.ReadLine() != expFile.ReadLine())
    {
         return false;
    }
}
return (outFile.EndOfStream && expFile.EndOfStream);
```

This will dispose of the using variables in the end of the scope of the variables, i.e. in the end of the method.

Comment: `using var outFile = new StreamReader(outputFile.OpenRead()),
     var expFile = new StreamReader(expectedFile.OpenRead());` also works

Comment: @Chazt3n No it does not. Implicitly-typed variables cannot have multiple declarators.

Answer (score 19):

if you don't mind declaring the variables for your using block before the using block, you could declare them all in the same using statement.

```
    Test t; 
    Blah u;
    using (IDisposable x = (t = new Test()), y = (u = new Blah())) {
        // whatever...
    }
```

That way, x and y are just placeholder variables of type IDisposable for the using block to use and you use t and u inside your code. Just thought i'd mention.

Comment: I feel like this would be confusing to a new developer looking at your code.

Comment: This can be a bad practice; it has a side-effect that the variables will still exist even after the unmanaged resourced have been freed. According to Microsoft's C# reference, "You can instantiate the resource object and then pass the variable to the using statement, but this is not a best practice. In this case, the object remains in scope after control leaves the using block even though it will probably no longer have access to its unmanaged resources."

Comment: @RobertAltman You're right, and in real code I would use another approach (probably the one from Gavin H). This is just a less preferrable alternative.

Comment: You could just move the declarations inside the using with typecasts.  Would that be better?

Answer (score 11):

The using statement works off of the IDisposable interface so another option could be to create some type of composite class that implements IDisposable and has references to all of the IDisposable objects you would normally put in your using statement. The down side to this is that you have to declare your variables first and outside of the scope for them to be useful within the using block requiring more lines of code than some of the other suggestions would require.

```
Connection c = new ...; 
Transaction t = new ...;

using (new DisposableCollection(c, t))
{
   ...
}
```

The constructor for DisposableCollection is a params array in this case so you can feed in as many as you like.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to compare the files efficiently, don't use StreamReaders at all, and then the usings aren't necessary - you can use low level stream reads to pull in buffers of data to compare.

You can also compare things like the file size first to quickly detect different files to save yourself having to read all the data, too.

Comment: Yeah, checking the file size is a good idea, saves you the time or reading all the bytes. (+1)

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the question, which is about nesting `using` statements (regardless of what the `using` statements contain). It should be a comment, instead.

Answer (score 7):

You can group multiple disposable objects in one using-statement with commas:

```
using (StreamReader outFile = new StreamReader(outputFile.OpenRead()), 
       expFile = new StreamReader(expectedFile.OpenRead()))
{

}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also say:

```
using (StreamReader outFile = new StreamReader(outputFile.OpenRead()))
using (StreamReader expFile = new StreamReader(expectedFile.OpenRead()))
{
   ...
}
```

But some people might find that hard to read. BTW, as an optimization to your problem, why dont you check that the file sizes are the same size first, before going line by line?

Answer (score 6):

You could omit the brackets on all but the inner-most using:

```
using (StreamReader outFile = new StreamReader(outputFile.OpenRead()))
using (StreamReader expFile = new StreamReader(expectedFile.OpenRead()))
{
  while (!(outFile.EndOfStream || expFile.EndOfStream))
  {
    if (outFile.ReadLine() != expFile.ReadLine())
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

I think this is cleaner than putting several of the same type in the same using, as others have suggested, but I'm sure many people will think this is confusing

Answer (score 6):

Also, if you already know the paths, there's no point is scanning the directory.

Instead, I would recommend something like this:

```
string directory = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"TestArea\");

using (StreamReader outFile = File.OpenText(directory + filename + ".out"))
using (StreamReader expFile = File.OpenText(directory + filename + ".exp")) 
{
    //...
```

[`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) will add a folder or filename to a path and make sure that there is exactly one backslash between the path and the name.

[`File.OpenText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.opentext.aspx) will open a file and create a `StreamReader` in one go.

By prefixing a string with @, you can avoid having to escape every backslash (eg, `@"a\b\c"`)

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing odd about it.  `using` is a shorthand way of ensuring the disposal of the object once the code block is finished.  If you have a disposable object in your outer block that the inner block needs to use, this is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 5):

And to just add to the clarity, in this case, since each successive statement is a single statement, (and not a block), you can omit all the brackets :

```
using (StreamReader outFile = new StreamReader(outputFile.OpenRead()))
  using (StreamReader expFile = new StreamReader(expectedFile.OpenRead()))
    while (!(outFile.EndOfStream || expFile.EndOfStream))  
       if (outFile.ReadLine() != expFile.ReadLine())    
          return false;
```

Comment: Interesting solution; doing this/even using the 1 set of brackets at lowest level maybe, accomplishes the same goal as stacking them left-justified (cleaner IMO), while addressing the cosmetic nesting desire others mentioned to show any subordination.

Answer (score 3):

These come up time to time when I code as well. You could consider move the second using statement into another function.

Answer (score 3):

Are you also asking if there is a better way to compare to files?
I prefer calculating a CRC or MD5 for both files and compare those.

For example you could use the following extension method:

```
public static class ByteArrayExtender
    {
        static ushort[] CRC16_TABLE =  { 
                      0X0000, 0XC0C1, 0XC181, 0X0140, 0XC301, 0X03C0, 0X0280, 0XC241, 
                      0XC601, 0X06C0, 0X0780, 0XC741, 0X0500, 0XC5C1, 0XC481, 0X0440, 
                      0XCC01, 0X0CC0, 0X0D80, 0XCD41, 0X0F00, 0XCFC1, 0XCE81, 0X0E40, 
                      0X0A00, 0XCAC1, 0XCB81, 0X0B40, 0XC901, 0X09C0, 0X0880, 0XC841, 
                      0XD801, 0X18C0, 0X1980, 0XD941, 0X1B00, 0XDBC1, 0XDA81, 0X1A40, 
                      0X1E00, 0XDEC1, 0XDF81, 0X1F40, 0XDD01, 0X1DC0, 0X1C80, 0XDC41, 
                      0X1400, 0XD4C1, 0XD581, 0X1540, 0XD701, 0X17C0, 0X1680, 0XD641, 
                      0XD201, 0X12C0, 0X1380, 0XD341, 0X1100, 0XD1C1, 0XD081, 0X1040, 
                      0XF001, 0X30C0, 0X3180, 0XF141, 0X3300, 0XF3C1, 0XF281, 0X3240, 
                      0X3600, 0XF6C1, 0XF781, 0X3740, 0XF501, 0X35C0, 0X3480, 0XF441, 
                      0X3C00, 0XFCC1, 0XFD81, 0X3D40, 0XFF01, 0X3FC0, 0X3E80, 0XFE41, 
                      0XFA01, 0X3AC0, 0X3B80, 0XFB41, 0X3900, 0XF9C1, 0XF881, 0X3840, 
                      0X2800, 0XE8C1, 0XE981, 0X2940, 0XEB01, 0X2BC0, 0X2A80, 0XEA41, 
                      0XEE01, 0X2EC0, 0X2F80, 0XEF41, 0X2D00, 0XEDC1, 0XEC81, 0X2C40, 
                      0XE401, 0X24C0, 0X2580, 0XE541, 0X2700, 0XE7C1, 0XE681, 0X2640, 
                      0X2200, 0XE2C1, 0XE381, 0X2340, 0XE101, 0X21C0, 0X2080, 0XE041, 
                      0XA001, 0X60C0, 0X6180, 0XA141, 0X6300, 0XA3C1, 0XA281, 0X6240, 
                      0X6600, 0XA6C1, 0XA781, 0X6740, 0XA501, 0X65C0, 0X6480, 0XA441, 
                      0X6C00, 0XACC1, 0XAD81, 0X6D40, 0XAF01, 0X6FC0, 0X6E80, 0XAE41, 
                      0XAA01, 0X6AC0, 0X6B80, 0XAB41, 0X6900, 0XA9C1, 0XA881, 0X6840, 
                      0X7800, 0XB8C1, 0XB981, 0X7940, 0XBB01, 0X7BC0, 0X7A80, 0XBA41, 
                      0XBE01, 0X7EC0, 0X7F80, 0XBF41, 0X7D00, 0XBDC1, 0XBC81, 0X7C40, 
                      0XB401, 0X74C0, 0X7580, 0XB541, 0X7700, 0XB7C1, 0XB681, 0X7640, 
                      0X7200, 0XB2C1, 0XB381, 0X7340, 0XB101, 0X71C0, 0X7080, 0XB041, 
                      0X5000, 0X90C1, 0X9181, 0X5140, 0X9301, 0X53C0, 0X5280, 0X9241, 
                      0X9601, 0X56C0, 0X5780, 0X9741, 0X5500, 0X95C1, 0X9481, 0X5440, 
                      0X9C01, 0X5CC0, 0X5D80, 0X9D41, 0X5F00, 0X9FC1, 0X9E81, 0X5E40, 
                      0X5A00, 0X9AC1, 0X9B81, 0X5B40, 0X9901, 0X59C0, 0X5880, 0X9841, 
                      0X8801, 0X48C0, 0X4980, 0X8941, 0X4B00, 0X8BC1, 0X8A81, 0X4A40, 
                      0X4E00, 0X8EC1, 0X8F81, 0X4F40, 0X8D01, 0X4DC0, 0X4C80, 0X8C41, 
                      0X4400, 0X84C1, 0X8581, 0X4540, 0X8701, 0X47C0, 0X4680, 0X8641, 
                      0X8201, 0X42C0, 0X4380, 0X8341, 0X4100, 0X81C1, 0X8081, 0X4040 };


        public static ushort CalculateCRC16(this byte[] source)
        {
            ushort crc = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
            {
                crc = (ushort)((crc >> 8) ^ CRC16_TABLE[(crc ^ (ushort)source[i]) & 0xFF]);
            }

            return crc;
        }
```

Once you've done that it's pretty easy to compare files:

```
public bool filesAreEqual(string outFile, string expFile)
{
    var outFileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(outFile);
    var expFileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(expFile);

    return (outFileBytes.CalculateCRC16() == expFileBytes.CalculateCRC16());
}
```

You could use the built in System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 class,
but the calculated hash is a byte[] so you'd still have to compare those two arrays.

Comment: Instead of taking a byte array, the method should take a `Stream` object and call the `ReadByte` method until it returns -1.  This will save large amounts of memory for large files.

Comment: How would you then calculate the crc over all the bytes?

Comment: Oh never mind what I said :p Thnx, I'll change that in my code :p
We only use it for data < 1000 bytes so haven't noticed problems yet but will change anyway

Comment: Every time you call `ReadByte` the stream's position advances by one byte.  Therefore, if you keep calling it until it returns -1 (EOF), it'll give you every byte in the file. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.readbyte.aspx

Comment: Using a CRC is great if you want to compare multiple files multiple times, but for a single comparison you have to read both files in their entirety to compute the CRCs - If you compare the data in small chunks then you can exit from the comparison as soon as you find a byte that differs.

Comment: Isn’t a `ushort` a little, eh, “short” of a hash? Depending on the level of assurance needed in determining that files exactly match or where the files being compared come from, I think this method is too likely to find find a hash collision.

Answer (score 3):

I think I may have found a syntactically cleaner way of declaring this using statement, and it appears to work for me? using var as your type in the using statement instead of IDisposable seems to dynamically infer type on both objects and allows me to instantiate both of my objects and call their properties and methods of the class they are allocated with, as in 
`using(var uow = new UnitOfWorkType1(), uow2 = new UnitOfWorkType2()){}.` 
If anyone knows why this isn't right, please let me know

Comment: Several on one line works if all the things are of the same type. Mixed types have to split over separate using()s. But it doesn't work with var, you have to specify a type (C# 5 specification, p237)

Answer (score 3):

Its the normal way of use and works perfect. Although there are some other ways of implementing this.
Almost every answer is already present in this question's response. But here I am listing all of them together.

**Already Used**

```
using (StreamReader outFile = new StreamReader(outputFile.OpenRead()))
  {
    using (StreamReader expFile = new StreamReader(expectedFile.OpenRead()))
    {
      while (!(outFile.EndOfStream || expFile.EndOfStream))
      {
        if (outFile.ReadLine() != expFile.ReadLine())
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
```

**Option 1**

```
using (StreamReader outFile = new StreamReader(outputFile.OpenRead()))
    using (StreamReader expFile = new StreamReader(expectedFile.OpenRead()))
    {
      while (!(outFile.EndOfStream || expFile.EndOfStream))
      {
        if (outFile.ReadLine() != expFile.ReadLine())
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
```

**Option 2**

```
using (StreamReader outFile = new StreamReader(outputFile.OpenRead()),
                    expFile = new StreamReader(expectedFile.OpenRead()))
   {
      while (!(outFile.EndOfStream || expFile.EndOfStream))
       {
         if (outFile.ReadLine() != expFile.ReadLine())
         return false;
       }
    }
```