# Formatting/indentation for using statements (C#)

Tags: c#, formatting, using-statement

When it comes to `using` statements in C# (not to be confused with `using` *directives* that import namespaces), Visual Studio doesn't indent single-line code that follows if no braces are employed. This is typical of "nesting" using statements as shown in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329739/nested-using-statements-in-c).

I find it confusing that subsequent statements after `using` are not indented, unlike the formatting of an `if` statement:

```
// non-indented using statement
using (var myResource = new SomeIDisposableResource())
myResource.Indent(false);

// indented if statement
if (something == true)
    IndentMe();
```

Is there any reason *not* to indent, or is it just preference?

```
// indented using statement, but not the default VS formatting
using (var myResource = new SomeIDisposableResource())
    myResource.Indent();
```

**EDIT:**

Further testing reveals that I was incorrect about some of the VS formatting behavior. If you type a using statement:

```
using (var myResource = SomeIDisposableResource())
```

...and hit enter, the cursor will align with `using`. If the next line is also a using statement, it will continue to align. If it is not, VS will indent it upon completion. Thus my original question is somewhat invalidated, because my first example is not really achievable unless you override the default formatting or use an IDE that doesn't do that.

Still, it is worth knowing that multiple `using` statements are best treated as a single block because they technically are. The lack of indentation only applies when the statements are sequential `using` statements without braces; and as one gets used to it, they stop looking so unusual.

As always thanks to all those who answered for the insight and experience in even these minor programming details.

Comment: I don't get it. Can you show examples of both styles? The question you linked to shows indented code... with curlies...

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes: Added examples as requested.

Comment: Works fine on my machine, it indents as soon as I type ;.  I did override the default settings though.

Comment: It indents by default. Even if you carefully remove the indentation, clicking Format Document restores it.

Comment: If you insist on skipping the braces I would stick the `using` statement and the `myResource.Indent()` call on the same line.  Though I prefer braces in this case.  I don't particularly mind `if (something == true) IndentMe();` as a one-liner, though.

Comment: @Brian: That's a conclusion, not an argument. I paid for an argument. An argument would explain what possible risk there is to omitting the braces while indenting the scoped statement.

Comment: @Steven: Further, the OP isn't even asking about whether to use braces or not.  That's why I wrote it as a comment rather than as an answer.

Comment: @Steven Sudit: Ah you are right regarding VS's auto-indentation. I should clarify that it doesn't when the next statement is another using statement. I hadn't tested that: I hit enter after the using statement and the cursor aligned. Once the semicolon concludes the statement, it indents as per my third example. I'll modify my question for accuracy, but nevertheless this is a useful discussion. :)

Comment: I have to agree with that. It's still possible for a reasonable person to to conclude that we should use braces despite this auto-formatting, but let's at least understand that there's a "despite" in there.

Comment: @Brian: Yes, I only made mine an answer when I realized I needed to be able to show code.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I didn't actually complete the statement before being puzzled by the fact the cursor had not already indented. Embarrassing, but still seems like a good Q&A on formatting as it pertains to the `using` blocks.

Comment: So, there's no real problem here, right?  I *do* dislike cargo culture answers, should I post mine?

Comment: @Hans: I think there's broad agreement in favor of indenting, particularly since this is enforced by the editor. I also think there's broad *dis*agreement with my stance against including the optional braces. I consider those to be an example of cargo-cult mentality, now that you mention it. Feel free to post your answer on either issue, of course.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As others have said, always use braces. However, there's *one* idiom which somewhat goes against this *and* uses the "non-indentation":

```
using (Resource1 res1 = new Resource1())
using (Resource2 res2 = new Resource2())
using (Resource3 res3 = new Resource3())
{
    // Do stuff with res1, res2 and res3
}
```

But I'd always use braces for the innermost block :)

Comment: Good call, I forgot about multiple using statements on top of each other.

Comment: The stack of using statements seems to go against my model of code dependencies. By that, I mean that I view indented code as being dependent on the preceding block with one less indent. Inserting some code between the using statements would seem okay based solely on formatting, but unless I am wrong, it would break the association between the statements. I guess this is just one of the occasional exceptions to the rule?

Comment: If you're inserting code between two lines, presumably you're looking at those lines.

Comment: @JYelton: Yes, it's an exception - I rarely find myself doing it anyway, to be honest, but it's useful to know about. Basically I mentally treat all the using statements as a block of them.

Comment: If we're going to allow stacking, then I'm not sure why we need the braces.

Comment: @Steven: I'm effectively treating all the using statements as one... I still want the braces to show the body of code to be executed.

Comment: The reason I used to use braces for this sort of thing in C++ is that it was all too easy to have two indented statements, so it looked like both would be in the block. In C# using VS as my editor, I can't do that accidentally, or even intentionally. It keeps correcting my error! This removes any motivation to use braces.

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer, so I could show samples. Feel free to downvote it. :-)

Comment: @recursive: Oh you're right, I don't have a need to insert code between them, but I can see a case where someone might erroneously try to. I just wanted to firm up on the matter. :)

Answer (score 13):

It's preference.  I always indent, and place the necessary items in brackets

```
using(var t = new t())
{
   t.Foo();
}
```

Comment: Even for single lines? I presume the braces then just force VS to indent according to your preference?

Comment: Yes, I even put it for single lines.  It's preference, but I have run into too many situations where someone accidentally comments or deletes something and an if statement extends it's control beyond where it should.  Sometimes its a massive headache that causes hours of debugging.  I follow the explicitly clear and better safe than sorry principle.

Comment: Kevin, were any of these situations in C# as opposed to C++ or C?

Comment: @JYelton: Keep in mind that VS will indent regardless of the braces.

Comment: @Steven, actually yes.  When I have had this happen in C# it is generally, because the code is bad to begin with.  It's confusing, and sometimes poorly done.  For a long time, I never thought this would make that much of a difference in a language like C# (compared to C++, C) it is a lot easier to understand.  And then i saw the C# code where it happened.  I was unbelievably frustrated when I figured out that was the problem.

Comment: @Kevin: Do you Format Document as part of your review process?

Comment: With the team I'm on now, yes we do.  This was on a different project where there was no code review process or real standards either (really no one wanted to look at that code more than they had to.)

Comment: @Kevin: That's kind of what I figured. When you have no standards and no review process, nothing works because nothing is enforced.

Comment: @Steven Sudit: What I failed to do was complete the statement I was writing with a semicolon to see that it would automatically indent. I was working off the position of the cursor upon hitting enter. The behavior is different in the IDE writing a using statement versus an if statement. I amended the question to reflect this. Apparently I need to ensure that I've allowed auto-formatting to do its work before I assume anything! :)

Comment: @JYelton: You're right: with `if`, it indents as soon as you hit enter. I'm guessing the reason it doesn't do this for `using` is precisely so you can stack them up as Jon did.

Answer (score 5):

Easy fix: always use explicit blocks, even for single lines. Visual Studio will then properly indent, and as a bonus your code will be more maintainable!

Comment: Do you mean more maintainable because braces affect variable scope?

Comment: @JYelton, not quite. More maintainable because if you later want to add a line there or remove it for debugging or something, the braces are already there, and you don't risk forgetting them and wasting hours debugging it.

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes: I've had such situations occur; definitely a good reason to always use braces.

Comment: It's impossible to forget them unless you're using Notepad or something. The VS editor prevents this error.

Answer (score 0):

Like my C instructor told me over 10 years ago: Always, always, always use the braces. Odds are good someone is going to come along (possibly even you) and throw in another line of code, then wonder why it's not behaving correctly.

Comment: Really? It's served me well since c# first came out. Why would you say it doesn't apply?

Answer (score 0):

I like being downvoted when I'm wrong, so I'm going to make an answer out of this...

Here's how I would format it:

```
using (Resource1 res1 = new Resource1())
using (Resource2 res2 = new Resource2())
using (Resource3 res3 = new Resource3())
  DoStuffWithResources(res1, res2, res3);
```

If I were to replace `DoStuffWithResources` with multiple statements, I would make use braces. However, my editor prevents me from ever making the following mistake:

```
using (Resource1 res1 = new Resource1())
using (Resource2 res2 = new Resource2())
using (Resource3 res3 = new Resource3())
  DoStuffWithResources(res1, res2, res3);
  DoOtherStuffWithResources(res1, res2, res3);
```

When I try to enter the above, I immediately get:

```
using (Resource1 res1 = new Resource1())
using (Resource2 res2 = new Resource2())
using (Resource3 res3 = new Resource3())
  DoStuffWithResources(res1, res2, res3);
DoOtherStuffWithResources(res1, res2, res3);
```

Pro tip: A downvote is not a counterargument, so if you don't have one, you shouldn't be voting.

Comment: My argument for using braces isn't because of what *I might do*, it is the next person that comes in that I do not trust.  Much like driving on a snowy road in winter - I know that I can take care of myself, it is everyone else driving that scares the living hell out of me.  Point given, you will recognize that the second isn't indented - but how about the Jr. that gets brought in to do defect work?

Comment: The next person is also using the VS editor, so the same thing prevents *them* from accidentally creating that second code block. If you're in a typical shop, code will be reviewed prior to being released or put into production. As part of code review, I always Format Document to ensure that nothing changes.

Comment: @Steven, code will be reviewed? I wish! If only the LOB saw such matters as clearly as programmers do.

Comment: @Anthony: It's actually fine if you downvoted -- you're allowed to be wrong. All I ask is that people offer a counterargument as opposed to a thumb. Your argument seems to be that some shops don't do code reviews. Sadly, you're right that these exist. However, you're also right in your implication that they suffer for this. Not much point talking about the benefits of one formatting over another if, in the end, you can get away with murder.

Comment: It turned out that I *did* downvote but didn't mean to. But on code reviews, I'm doing work on a team for a rather large financial company. The LOB is paying for enhancements. We (meaning the grunts) all agree that code reviews would be nice. Refactoring obscenely long methods would be wonderful. (And I do mean *obscenely* long.) It would be so much better for the LOB in the long run. They don't care about the long run, they care about the next release. But don't mind me, I'm basically just venting now.

Comment: @Anthony: We've all been there. Some of us are there now, the rest of us will be there again sooner or later. Vent if you must; it's slightly better than exploding, though not nearly as good as finding a better job. :-)

Comment: @joseph.ferris: I replied to your comment but forgot to prefix it.