# List of strings wont get written completely to text file

Tags: c#, .net, stream

I Im trying to read from one text file and write to another one. The file Im reading from has 2023 lines, and the file that I am writing to comes out with only 2008 lines. I cant figure out what is happening to the other line... Im losing them somewhere. What am I doing wrong?

thanks!

heres my code in C#.

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:/Users/Rafael/desktop/newfile.txt");
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:/Users/Rafael/desktop/new1.txt");//, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {

            writer.WriteLine(line);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are the lines missing from the end of the file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At no point here are you closing the streamwriter - so it might not be written to the file.  You can test this by putting a Close() call after the loop, or if you have not finished with the file, you can use Flush().

Given a choice, I would however rewrite the code to use `Using{}` blocks which would close the streams automatically by calling Dispose() when they go out of scope.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely is that the output isn't being flushed since you aren't calling `Dispose()` on the writer, so the buffered output is being thrown away.

When you're using classes that implement `IDisposable` in this way, you should always wrap them in `using` blocks:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:/Users/Rafael/desktop/newfile.txt"))
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:/Users/Rafael/desktop/new1.txt"))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {

            writer.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well, I would say "if possible" wrap them in using blocks; that won't work if you are opening a file to be used and stored through multiple calls, say, in a member variable.

Comment: @shelleybutterfly: Then the thing that owns the `StreamWriter` should itself implement `IDisposable` and call `StreamWriter.Dispose` in the implementation of `Dispose` for that thing.

Comment: @shelleybutterfly: by  "using classes" I meant in-line code like this. Of course, what you've said is correct, and the containing class should then be `IDisposable` and so on.

Comment: @Yahia: Actually, he wasn't. The syntax he had is [perfectly legal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329739/nested-using-statements-in-c/1329757#1329757) for `using` blocks.

Comment: @Jason: I'd rather point out that omitting braces is legal around *any* single-statement block. Saying it like that makes `using` seem special, when it isn't.

Comment: @Porges - I totally agree with your approach in this case, however 'always' is a strong word. I use and write classes that implement IDisposable for lots of reasons, and it isn't always possible to put them in a Using{} block.  You might have to retain a reference to the object at a class scope, in which case I dispose of it at some specific other point, such as in a Dispose() method of the encapsulating class.

Comment: @iandotkelly, shelleybutterfly: I amended the sentence to say "when youre using [them] in this way" to clear that up :P

Answer (score 3):

This is where implementation details matter a lot. Basically when you write to a `StreamWriter`, the text that you write isn't necessarily committed to the file on the disk. Instead, it could sit in a buffer somewhere and that buffer has to be flushed to be committed to the disk. Periodically, this buffer will be flushed by the `StreamWriter` itself. But if you let your process terminate without making a final flush, the buffer could still hold uncommitted writes.

So, call `writer.Flush`, `writer.Close`, `writer.Dispose`, or best of all, wrap your use of the `StreamWriter` in a `using` block so that it's disposed for you.

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you are not wanting to close the file. You could use [flush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

`ReadLine()` returns an empty string when the line doesn't contain any characters...
Call `Flush()` and `Close()` ... consider using `using`...

Why aren't you just copying the file as a whole ([`File.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx)) ?

Comment: I didnt use File.Copy because i had to do some sorting on the strings before I could write it back to the new file. But calling flush() solved my problem.
thanks for the help.