# Wrapping multiple IDisposables with using gives CA2202

Tags: c#, idisposable

When I wrap IDisposable objects in usings like this I get the code analysis warning Code analysis error `CA2202: Do not dispose objects multiple times`, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182334.aspx

```
using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
{
    using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, value);
    }
    return textWriter.ToString();
}
```

This however doesn't return any errors

```
using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
{
    XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings);
    serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, value);
    return textWriter.ToString();
}
```

Also when doing this the xmlWriter dispose will trigger CA2202

```
StringWriter textWriter = null;
XmlWriter xmlWriter = null;

try
{
    textWriter = new StringWriter();
    xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings);
    serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, value);
    return textWriter.ToString();
}
finally
{
    if (textWriter != null)
        textWriter.Dispose();
    // The xmlWriter dispose will trigger CA2202
    if (xmlWriter != null)
        xmlWriter.Dispose();
}
```

Which pattern shall I use? It seems strange to not dispose disposable elements.

Answer (score 2):

Ath the end of the inner using statement `XmlWriter` is being disposed. When this happens the `textWriter` element is also disposed because `XmlWriter` internally disposes object it wraps.

Since Dispose should be idempotent (repeatable calls does not have side effects) I wouldn't worry about this warning.

Answer (score 1):

A simple google find this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8096857/2027232

The problem isn't because of the nested usings.  They're fine and generally recommended.  The problem here is that `XmlReader` will dispose the `TextReader` if you pass an `XmlReaderSettings` with `CloseInput == true`, but the CA2202 rule isn't smart enough that your code won't go down that branch.  Keep your nested usings, and suppress the CA2202 violation as a false positive.  If you want to be extra careful, use an `XmlReaderSettings` with `CloseInput` set to `false`, but that is the default value, so it's not strictly necessary.

BTW, there are similar CA2202 problem scenarios for a variety of stream and reader types.  Unfortunately, they're not all the same as this one, so the best case handling can differ depending on which type is cause the problem.