# Can you dispose of multiple objects within a Using block?

Tags: c#, .net

How to take care of multiple objects getting disposed off in a Using statement?

**Sample code**

```
using(MyClass obj = new MyClass())
{
    MyOtherClass objOC= new MyOtherClass()
    TextReader objTR = new StringReader(...);  
    // other code
}
```

`MyClass obj` will be be disposed at the end of the Using block, but then what about 
`MyOtherClass objOC` and `TextReader objTR`. As far as I know it they wont get disposed, so should I be having a nested Using block there, like this below? I will need a real wide screen monitor if the number of objects increase

**Is this below correct?**

```
using(MyClass obj = new MyClass())
{
    using (MyOtherClass objOC= new MyOtherClass())
    {
        using (TextReader objTR = new StringReader(...))
        {
           //code using all three objects 
        }   
    } 
    // other code using just `MyClass obj`
}
```

MyClass & MyOtherClass both implement `IDisposable`

Comment: related: [Nested using statements in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329739/nested-using-statements-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Yes, your code is correct. Here's a couple other things you might want to be aware of...

You can declare multiple objects of the same type in a single using statement. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
using (Font font3 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f), 
            font4 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f))
{
    // Use font3 and font4.
}
```

For using multiple objects of different types you can nest using the one-line syntax to save space:

```
using (MyClass obj = new MyClass())
using (MyOtherClass objOC= new MyOtherClass())
using (TextReader objTR = new StringReader(...))
{
    // code using all three objects 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you want to gurantee the `Dispose(..)` call on all of them you have to enclose them inside `using` statment like in second example.

Or you can declare multiple objects inside single `using` statement. It's a matter of coding style and code flow.