# Properly disposing a WebRequest and StreamReader

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, httpwebrequest

I'm getting an object disposed exception during a call to the ReadToEnd method from a client side method, getRecords, that communicates to a webserver using a StreamReader.

The first call to getRecords succeeds, it is only during a subsequent call the exception occurs, and so I'm not closing and disposing of the StreamReader and associated WebRequest properly.

I'm aware that I could wrap these two objects in a using statement, however that just gets expanded into a try/catch/finally statement. As can be seen in my code below, I'm cleaning up in my finally clause.

Therefore, **I'm either not doing something that the using statment does, or there is something else I may be missing in my finally statment.** I'd rather not using the using statment if at all possible, as I like my code explicit.

Here is the code and the associated exception:

```
    public int getRecords(string[] args, string[] vals)
    {
        List<string> urlList = BuildUrlRequestStrings(args, vals); 

        WebRequest request = null;
        WebResponse wresponse = null;
        StreamReader sr = null;           

        foreach (string url in urlList)
        {   
            request = WebRequest.Create(url);

            request.Method = "GET";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            //request.Timeout = -1;
            request.Timeout = 300000;
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            //request.ContentType = "application/xml";

            try
            {
                wresponse = request.GetResponse();

                /*using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wresponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    _recieveBuffer = sr.ReadToEnd().ToString();
                }*/
                sr = new StreamReader(wresponse.GetResponseStream());
                _recieveBuffer = sr.ReadToEnd();

                //List<T> temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(_recieveBuffer);
                List<T> temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(
                    _recieveBuffer,
                    new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All }
                );

                _recieveData.AddRange(temp);                    
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Response != null)
                {
                    // can use ex.Response.Status, .StatusDescription         
                    if (ex.Response.ContentLength != 0)
                    {
                        using (var stream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream())
                        {
                            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                            {
                                Log.Info(FIDB.TAG1, "   WSBuffer.getRecords: WEBSERVER MESSAGE: " + reader.ReadToEnd());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                return -1;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (sr != null)
                {
                    sr.Close();
                    sr.Dispose();
                }

                if (wresponse != null)
                {
                    wresponse.Close();
                    wresponse.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }

        return _recieveData.Count;
    }
```

---

> 07-02 11:32:15.076: I/<<< FI >>>(2775):
>   StorageRelayService.RequestQueueThread: EXCEPTION:
>   System.ObjectDisposedException: The object was used after being
>   disposed. 07-02 11:32:15.076: I/<<< FI >>>(2775):   at
>   System.Net.WebConnection.BeginRead (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request,
>   System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, System.AsyncCallback
>   cb, System.Object state) [0x00000] in :0  07-02
>   11:32:15.076: I/<<< FI >>>(2775):   at
>   System.Net.WebConnectionStream.BeginRead (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, Int32 size, System.AsyncCallback cb, System.Object state)
>   [0x00000] in :0  07-02 11:32:15.076: I/<<< FI
>
> > > > (2775):   at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.Read (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) [0x00000] in :0 
> > > >         07-02 11:32:15.076: I/<<< FI >>>(2775):   at
> > > >         System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer () [0x00000] in :0
> > > >         07-02 11:32:15.076: I/<<< FI >>>(2775):   at
> > > >         System.IO.StreamReader.Read (System.Char[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32
> > > >         count) [0x00000] in :0  07-02 11:32:15.076: I/<<< FI
> > > >         (2775):   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEnd () [0x00000] in :0  07-02 11:32:15.076: I/<<< FI >>>(2775):   at
> > > >         FieldInspection.Shared.Buffer.WSBuffer`1[FieldInspection.Shared.Model.AggregateRoot.Parcel].getRecords
> > > >         (System.String[] args, System.String[] vals) [0x00000] in <filename
> > > >         unknown>:0  07-02 11:32:15.076: I/<<< FI >>>(2775):   at
> > > >         FieldInspection.Shared.Repository.REST.RepositoryREST`1[FieldInspection.Shared.Model.AggregateRoot.Parcel].Read
> > > >         (IConditions conditions) [0x00000] in :0  07-02
> > > >         11:32:15.076: I/<<< FI >>>(2775):   at
> > > >         FieldInspection.Shared.Model.DataAccess.ParcelRepositoryREST.parcelByIdList
> > > >         (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 parcelIdList, Boolean bCurrent,
> > > >         Boolean bHistorical) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0  07-02
> > > >         11:32:15.076: I/<<< FI >>>(2775):   at
> > > >         FieldInspection.Droid.StorageRelayService.ProcessRequestGetParcelCache
> > > >         (FieldInspection.Shared.Database.IPC.Request request) [0x00000] in
> > > >         <filename unknown>:0  07-02 11:32:15.076: I/<<< FI >>>(2775):   at
> > > >         FieldInspection.Droid.StorageRelayService.ProcessRequestFromForegroundActivity
> > > >         (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 reqList) [0x00000] in :0  07-02 11:32:15.076: I/<<< FI >>>(2775):   at
> > > >         FieldInspection.Droid.StorageRelayService.RequestQueueThread ()
> > > >         [0x00000] in :0

Comment: You could clean your using statements up with the following : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329739/nested-using-statements-in-c-sharp

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't want to just go with a `using` statement?

Comment: @Jeff Hubbard I don't like the "unkown" factor of when and where the finally clause and dispose statment is called when the using statment is expanded, and the foreach loop is a perfect example here. As stated, I'm not supposed to call dispose before the loop exists, b/c the object will be instantiated again, thus setting to null instead (as suggested). If you see my comment in the answer below, I ask "would the compiler know not to call dispose until the loop exited". These are the uncertainties I like to avoid.

Comment: @SamusArin - If the `using` was inside the `foreach`, then the object would be garbage collected after each iteration, as if you started your `foreach` with `StreamReader sr = null;`.  If the `using` wrapped the `foreach`, then you wouldn't be able to assign to it from within it, so it wouldn't need to repeatedly close.  This is a perfect example of why using `using` is a good thing - you know exactly what scope that stream is valid for, and you never leave it in an in-between state.

Comment: @Bobson Well ok then, I'll give the using statment a try, now that I know how it works. Sage tip, thank you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Make use of `using` which will close your connection once it loses scope.

Comment: -1: setting to `null` has no effect, and sometimes even a negative effect.

Comment: Ahh, I remember running into a similar situation with my connection to a (local) sqlite db, in the same app. I had to clean up in a very specific order. This is good info, thank you. So, if a "using" statment was used within a foreach, would the compiler know not to call dispose until the loop exited (I'll decompile eventually to investigate) ?

Comment: Setting to null was in conjunction to calling `Dispose`, which should allow reuse of the object in the foreach. Sticking with `using` and pushing the `Exception` upstream is certainly preferred, or to stick with calling `Close` and not `Dispose`.

Comment: I had to set to objects to null for my sqlite connections to clean up and not leave file pointers open: if (_rdr != null)
            {
                _rdr.Close();
                _rdr = null;
            }

            if (_cmd != null)
            {
                _cmd.Dispose();
                _cmd = null;
            }

            if (_con != null)
            {
                _con.Close();
                _con = null;
            }

Comment: @Aaron McIver "Setting to null was in conjunction to calling Dispose"... Did you mean "to calling Close" ?

Comment: @Aaron McIver No problem, thank you. Have a good holiday, too !)

Comment: @Aaron McIver ... actually, calling Close alone, without setting to null works (for my specific case, and only after a few tests). Nonethess, your help got it working for me, and gave me the insight I needed.

Comment: @SamusArin For clarification, setting to `null` if you call `Dispose`; otherwise calling `Close` should suffice without the need to set to `null` as you have stated.

Answer (score 2):

I'd highly suggest you to use "using" statement. Once you know your WebResponse and StreamReader disposed properly, it becomes easier to debug.

Also, you create a WebRequest object for each iteration of your loop. Why don't you try an asycnhronous approach?

This post might be helpful: [How to use HttpWebRequest (.NET) asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202481/how-to-use-httpwebrequest-net-asynchronously)

Comment: Well, using hides the finally clause that the compiler ends up generating, so I don't really see how this helps in understanding how the SR and WR get disposed. Also, I stated that I don't prefer the using statment (too obscure, and "magical"). The loop is actually to facilitate a url string that exceeds the size limit, and so each request is a sub request, and so sequential is fine. I'm taking the loop out anyway, since I can pass arguments in a JSON serialized object (which hides them as well). Thanks for tip about async tho.

Comment: You're welcome. I see, you may not prefer the using statement, but since it ensures your objects will be disposed when they're done, you won't get lost in try{..}catch{..}finally{...} blocks. I personally find it easier to use.

Comment: Well, Bobson's answer above cleared up my confustion/uncertainty with the using statments behavior, and b/c every time these concerns come up people overwhelmingly suggest to use using statment, I'm going start as well. I really wanted to do clean up manually until I understood whats happening; I think I'm ready :)

Answer (score 1):

I know you already accepted an answer, but an alternative solution would be to put the variable declarations *inside* the `foreach` loop.

```
foreach (string url in urlList)
{ 
    WebRequest request = null;
    WebResponse wresponse = null;
    StreamReader sr = null;  
    ...
}
```

Then each loop will get it's own instance, and `.Dispose()` will work as you expect.

Comment: Heh, you may not believe me, but I did have them just like that, but commented out. I tried all sorts of things, but it was blind experimentation. This info about how Dispose works in this case is super crucial, I'm so glad you posted this! Thanks a lot. I'm going to try this out too.

Comment: To expand on this answer:  If Samus had added `sr = null;` after `sr.Dispose();`, then he could be sure that the `sr` from first iteration was never referred to again. Moving the declaration (with setting to null) inside of the loop is another way to be certain that each iteration is independent.

Answer (score 0):

If your first run is ok and you get problems at some next runs, so it's most probably because the garbage collector didn't clean up closed objects. Do following in the end of `finally` block.

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Comment: I'll give that a shot, I'm interested to see if will alleviate this situation (I got working now, but I still want to verify this). This is good info in general, thank you.

Comment: @SamusArin I had the same problem like you. Closing, disposing and setting everything to null didn't help. Just manual GC call solved it. You are welcome :)

Comment: IMHO, this is a "sledgehammer" approach, that should be used sparingly. Good after a phase of a long running task, that you want to make sure is in a clean state before continuing. And is handy for debugging: if this helps, then somewhere there is a missing `using` or `dispose`. Try to get your code to work without this, then use it as an insurance policy, at a time where you don't mind an indeterminately long pause. If you find yourself doing this a lot, that suggests a deeper problem. Maybe even time to add a sub-process you can kill if needed (though that may complicate your code).

Comment: ... On the other hand, I also ran into a case where this was the only way out:  Had a lot of DirectX/XNA code mixed with .NET code, in a 32-bit process. Terrible fragmentation, until forcibly cleaned it up periodically with logic like this.

Comment: NOTE: in Samus case, this would not have helped. He did not do `sr = null;` after `sr.Dispose();`, so his code was still holding on to a reference to that disposed instance. Usually a variable goes out of scope before this is a problem, so the variable goes away on its own, but it is safest to always set to null after Dispose. (Presumably in Samus case, a WebException at the wrong moment kept `sr` from being set again in the second iteration, so the Disposed `sr` from first iteration was used, which is not allowed.)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve it's rather a workaround, not a solution. I had to use it with external libraries a couple of times. In the own code it is not the way to fix exceptions. We used this code on the site with many visitors to keep it responsible. Otherwise if it runs using it's own scheduler, the site might be not responsible for a couple of seconds