# Is it OK to use `using` like this?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nested using statements in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329739/nested-using-statements-in-c-sharp)

I'm a big fan of the `using` statement in C#. I find this:

```
using (var foo = new ObjectWhichMustBeDisposed())
{
    other code
}
```

...very much more readable than this:

```
var foo = new ObjectiWhichMustBeDisposed();

try
{
    other code
}
finally
{
    foo.Dispose();
}
```

Not only is it more readable, it also prevents accidental use of the `foo` variable after the `using` statement (i.e. after it has been disposed), whereas in the second example `foo` could be used after it had been disposed.

One problem with `using`, though, is that it tends to lead to very nested code if lots of disposable objects are being created. For example:

```
using (var foo = new ObjectWhichMustBeDisposed())
{
    using (var bar = new ObjectWhichMustBeDisposed())
    {
        other code
    }
}
```

If both the objects are of the same type, then you can combine them into a single `using` statement, like so:

```
using (var foo = new ObjectWhichMustBeDisposed(),
           bar = new ObjectWhichMustBeDisposed())
{
    other code
}
```

However, if the objects are not of the same type, then this will not work.

My question is whether it is OK to to achieve a similar end like this:

```
using (var foo = new ObjectWhichMustBeDisposed())
using (var bar = new OtherObjectWhichMustBeDisposed())
{
    other code
}
```

In this case, there are no curly-braces after the first using (and hence no need to indent the code). This compiles, and I *assume* that this works just like an `if` statement with no braces - i.e. it'll use the next statment (the second `using` in this case) as its "body".

Can anyone confirm whether that's correct? (The [description of the using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) is no help).

Comment: It certainly works. If it's OK is between you and your coding style.

Comment: Yes, it's completely correct :)

Comment: It compiles fine the only thing that I would say is that for readability and consistency stick with a style of wrapping code blocks around `{ }`

Comment: Sorry I don't actually have an answer for you, just wanted to say I like this latter approach and use it a lot in order to reduce nesting, especially when using sql commands/connections etc

Comment: I dont see problems with the indentation of several disposable objects. However I would make the code more readable using methods to encapsulate some behaviour.

Comment: This is completely legitimate. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329739/nested-using-statements-in-c-sharp the selected answer.

Comment: No matter if that's correct, I would say : *Be kind to the one who will maintain your code and keep the curly braces :p*

Comment: @hoang I consider it kinder to future readers to *omit* the curly braces.  It makes the code *easier* to read, not harder, and is a common enough pattern that it shouldn't be too surprising.

Comment: As long as it's consistent throughout the application, omitting the curly braces is fine. I rarely wrap a single statement or block in curly braces myself.

Comment: @Servy Have fun and put some line breaks and comments between using statements to see how readable it is :p

Comment: @hoang If line breaks and comments reduce readability, then either omit them or move them to a more suitable location in which they don't hamper readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at `using` statement definition in C# standard:

> 12.3.3.17 Using statements
>   For a using statement stmt of the form:
>   using ( resource-acquisition ) *embedded-statement*

*embedded-statement* is whatever from the following (See Item A2.5):

> *embedded-statement*:
>      block
>      empty-statement
>      expression-statement
>      selection-statement
>      iteration-statement
>      jump-statement
>      try-statement
>      checked-statement
>      unchecked-statement
>      lock-statement
>      using-statement
>      yield-statement

So both usages of `using` (block or another using-statement) are absolutely equivalent from C# Standard point of view.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who responded, and sorry I can't accept you all, but I thought it better to accept this answer - which is definitive / backed up with evidence.

Answer (score 7):

Yes the code you propose

```
using (var foo = new ObjectWhichMustBeDisposed())
using (var bar = new OtherObjectWhichMustBeDisposed())
{
    other code
}
```

is both OK and quite common.

You do not need to use additional { } after each *using* (other than the one that contains *other code*, if *other code* is more than one statement) because each using has exactly one statement following it.

```
using (var foo = new ObjectWhichMustBeDisposed())
using (var bar = new OtherObjectWhichMustBeDisposed())
using (var baz = new OtherObjectWhichMustBeDisposed())
using (var quux = new OtherObjectWhichMustBeDisposed())
{
    other code
}
```

would also be fine.

Comment: This is also true for any structured statement like `if`, `while` and so on.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Except `try`/`catch`. [Here's why](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/04/why-are-braces-required/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct.

```
using (var foo = new ObjectWhichMustBeDisposed())
using (var bar = new OtherObjectWhichMustBeDisposed())
{
    other code
}
```

So the rest is up to you. If you like this coding way, go with it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's correct; however it may not be good coding style for you.

There was a lengthy discussion on SO regarding this: [Why is it considered a bad practice to omit curly braces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359732/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-omit-curly-braces) In the post the OP specifically mentions using statements. It may be worth the read.