# Visual Studio 2015's behaviour in nested using statements

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

From a [similar question asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1329765/465056), it is known that the preferred way of indenting nested `using` statements is (which is pre-Visual Studio 2015's default):

```
using (var enumerator1 = list1.GetEnumerator())
using (var enumerator2 = list2.GetEnumerator())
{
    // Use enuemrator1 and enumerator2 here
}
```

However, I found the behaviour was changed in Visual Studio 2015, when I type the following:

```
using (var enumerator1 = list1.GetEnumerator())
```

and hit <kbd>↵</kbd>, the cursor is indented on the second line:

```
using (var enumerator1 = list1.GetEnumerator())
    ‸ // Text caret appears here instead of at the same level of
     // indent of the previous line
```

How can I get the old behaviour back and what is the rationale of changing this behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have ReSharper, you need to untick the setting named `Indent nested "using" statements`.

It can be found in the `Code Editing` section => `C#` => `Formatting Style` => `Other`.

[image: ReSharper Option]

---

Even if the option is unticked, the caret will still appears with an indentation. However, once you make a newline, ReSharper will format your `using` block correctly:

[image: ReSharper formatting kicking in]

Comment: I have ReSharper installed and I just verified that the checkbox is unchecked. Still not working :(

Comment: @rexcfnghk You need to make a newline after typing the second `using` statement, it'll format itself properly. I added a gif.