# Use using to dispose resources

Tags: c#, .net

I just started to use "using" to make sure resources are disposed regardless of what happens.

Below is an example of some code that I have written to retrieve some data. My question is:

*Are all the "using" required or would it be enough to just have the first one?*

```
        SomeMethod()
        {
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("myConnection"))
            {
                cn.Open();

                using (SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "myQuery";
                    using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if(rdr.HasRows)
                        {
                            while (rdr.Read())
                                // do something
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Short answer: all are required.

Comment: Ok I thought so - makes sense (although sure there is a lot more going on than I am aware of).

Comment: Even if one wouldn't be required because `Dispose` does nothing importan, it is better to use the `using`. Why? Because you don't know it and it's implementing `IDisposable`, normally not for no reason.

Comment: Worth noting that in some circumstances you can [chain `using`'s together](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1329765/791010) to reduce indentation etc.

Comment: well, you do have to add the code `cn.Close()` though.

Comment: @jackjop nope - [Either way, when the using block is exited (either by successful completion or by error) it is closed.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4717802/1441)

Comment: hmm, I should read some books maybe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using is nothing else than :

```
SomeClass o = null;
try 
{ 
   // managed resource that you use
   o = new SomeClass();  
   // ... some other code  here
}
finally 
{
  if(o != null)
    o.Dispose();
}
```

There is nothing wrong with a fact that you use `using` statement when it is possible (class implements `IDisposable` interface). When you want to use some *managed resource* then *use using*   :)

Comment: The declaration of `o` in your example needs to be before the try

Answer (score 2):

Using is a shortcut for the following pattern:

```
IDisposable resource = .....;
try
{
}
finally
{
    if (resource != null)
        resource.Dispose();
}
```

I would strongly suggest to use `using` always when using resources which need to be disposed or have the `IDisposable` interface implemented. Reason is that you don't know the implementation behind and it's much safer this way to prevent memory leaks or other code issues.

Answer (score 1):

> Are all the "using" required or would it be enough to just have the first one?

If any object which you use is implementing `IDisposable`, you can use `using`  statement, which will auto-disposing your object, or you can disposing (closing for any streams and etc) your object manually without `using`, just calling `Dispose()`.

So, for all objects which can be disposed better use `using` statement.