# how to handle exception if finally follows try block

Tags: java

If i put only finally without catch block how exception will be handled

Comment: Related question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954656/loss-exception-in-block-catch/3954759#3954759 with JLS citations.

Answer (score 3):

The exception will be passed up the call stack, as if the your try block did not exist, except the code in the finally will be executed.

Some example code

```
try {

   // an exception may be thrown somewhere in here

}
finally {
   // I will be executed, regardless of an exception thrown or not
}
```

Comment: According to the example from the Java Language Specification referenced in Stephen C's answer, the finally block will be executed regardless, it will be executed **before** anything further up the stack catches it, and if the finally block exits abnormally (e.g. with `return`), the exception will not propagate up the stack.

Answer (score 2):

Your exception will not be caught but the 'finally' block will be called and executed eventually. You can write a quick method as below and check it out :

```
public void testFinally(){
        try{
            throw new RuntimeException();

        }finally{
            System.out.println("Finally called!!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: The finally block will executed anyway, not eventually!

Comment: Right, the finally block will be executed **before** the exception propagates.

Answer (score 2):

> If i put only finally without catch block how exception will be handled

In that situation, the exception will not caught or handled.  What happens, depends on what happens in the `finally` clause.

- If the statement sequence in the `finally` clause completes "normally", the original exception will continue propagating.
- If the statement sequence in the `finally` clause completes "abruptly" for some reason then the entire `try` statement terminates for *that* reason.  Abrupt terminations include throwing an exception, executing a `return`, `break` or `continue`.  In this case, the original exception is lost without ever being "handled".

This has some rather interesting consequences.  For example, the following squashes any exceptions thrown in the try block.

```
public void proc () {
    try {
        // Throws some exception
    } finally {
        return;
    }
}
```

The details of `try` statements with `finally` clauses are set out in [JLS 14.20.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.20.2)

Comment: This seems to be the only correct answer. It's certainly the only one that gives a reference backing up its claims.