# How to get the Soap XML from a web service and store it in a string?

Tags: xml, web-services, soap

I have web service written that generates some data...can I call the web service in a way that i can store the xml soap representation of data...instead of actually calling the method that returns the actual data..i want to store the xml representation in a string ...

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the actual soap http response - the whole thing - and store it in a string?  Or you want to call a method on your webservice that returns a string that happens to be xml?

Comment: What kind of service do you mean? And what's your platform? Java, C#, what?

Comment: I want to get the actual soap http response - the whole thing - and store it in a string...in asp.net C#

Comment: What kind of service? ASMX? WCF? That really matters.

Comment: Ya it is actually asmx service..sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WCF, you could just simply [enable tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) and let the WCF runtime handle all the messy logging and tracing, and then just simply view the messages in the [Service Trace Viewer Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx) and [more info and screenshots here](http://offroadcoder.com/2008/06/19/ServiceTraceViewer.aspx).

Simple, easy - a few config entries and you're done.

If you insist on staying on the "legacy" ASMX technology, check out this SO post:

[Capturing SOAP requests to an ASP.NET ASMX web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624621/capturing-soap-requests-to-an-asp-net-asmx-web-service)

or have a look at this CodeProject article: [Trace SOAP Request/Response XML with TraceExtension](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38986/Trace-SOAP-Request-Response-XML-with-TraceExtensio.aspx)