# Return request HttpModules as quickly as possible

Tags: iis-7, httpmodule

In a web site I capture the http POST request with a HttpModule as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624621/capturing-soap-requests-to-an-asp-net-asmx-web-service/2624996#2624996).

After reading the body of the POST in the context's BeginRequest event I would like to return as quickly as possible an "OK" response to the client.
What would be the best way to prevent further processing in IIS (7.5 integrated mode)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this one is the fastest:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();

Response.StatusCode = 200;
Response.StatusDescription = "OK";

Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Comment: `CompleteRequest` will halt the request.  The Gerard wants to actually send an OK response.

Comment: "CompleteRequest" is implicitly called by "Response.End". But in a latter case you'll most likely get a ThreadAbordException (see the following KB article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629). I've added a Response.Flush (although I don't think that Gerard wanted to send something except the status code).

Comment: .End() gives a ThreadAbordException while .CompleteRequest() doesn't. On the other hand .Clear(), .ClearHeaders(), .Flush() do not seem to add anything. Response.Write("OK") gives an OK response in the body also when using CompleteRequest().

Answer (score 1):

Call `HttpResponse.End()`.  It will flush any pending content (your OK response) and then end the request.