# how use fiddler to check traffic of a web service between two web sites?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, http, fiddler

how can we use fiddler to check traffic of a web service(xml) between two web sites?
http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

i have created two subdomains for my web site.
for example my web site is like this :

> www.site.com

and those subdomains are like below :

> www.sub1.site.com
>
> www.sub2.site.com

these sites are on a web server (vps) and i am waching them with my local system(fiddler has been installed on my local system).
www.sub1.site.com is calling the www.sub2.site.com web service.
is it possible to capture this web service data with breakpoint like http and other stuff?
i checked fiddler many many times, but could n't find how?
if not what is the XML tab in Fiddler?

really appreciate for answer and help

Comment: Are these sites running locally?

Comment: nope, on a web server(vps).so i want to capture them with my local system as their client!

Comment: I don't think that from your local system you can capture the traffic between two sites on a remote server. How the TCP traffic is supposed to run through your local machine?

Comment: i think there should be a way as Requests/Responses (http/heasers/etc)can be captured by fiddler.what is the difference between them and xml stuff?

Comment: one site (a web server) sends a request (through web service) and recieve his answer from the other site (the other or same web server).we have xml stuff here instead of http...

Comment: if fiddler can not do this job is(are) there another tool(s)?

Comment: Can't you find out what you want from the web logs?  The Client IP address will be your server IP address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use Fiddler2 for this.  Fiddler2 is a web proxy that routes your browser requests through a proxy running on your own machine.  So it only works if the "client" that is making the HTTP request is local.  Your browser may, for example, initiate an HTTP request to www.sub1.site.com, but the call from www.sub1.site.com to www.sub2.site.com isn't one that will route through Fiddler2.  Think of Fiddler2 as sitting between your browser and whatever site the browser is trying to reach.

If you have access to install Fiddler2 on the server (sub1), you might consider http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/reverseproxy.asp for some more complex scenarios.  But then, if you have access to the server, there are other ways to monitor that may be better options (log files, as an example).

Comment: thanks for the answer, so is it possible to that job with other ways(tools) or impossible?

Comment: I am not aware of other tools options (I am sure they exist, though).  I am assuming you have access to the server.  Given that, your web server can be configured to log details about the incoming requests.  That is one mechanism.  Another would be to build some logging into the service to log the requests it receives from the server.  Since you tagged this question with C# and asp.net, you might look into adding logging in the Application_BeginRequest method of global.asax.cs.  Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624621/capturing-soap-requests-to-an-asp-net-asmx-web-service

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624621/capturing-soap-requests-to-an-asp-net-asmx-web-service shows an example of how to do this in one of the non-accepted answers which has several votes.

Comment: thanks for comments. please see this video -> video 1 on http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/video/ . i am looking for a job like this on web services.  i want to learn it's possible or not!

Comment: Just to be clear here, Fiddler can easily do this if it's run on either of the servers in question.