# Fiddler cannot capture web server traffic?

Tags: c#, fiddler

I've been stuck on this problem for hours at this point and I can't figure out the problem.

i would like to integrate "FiddlerCore" into my application , but its seem like only

get the request and response from localhost ? can i capture web server traffic ?

any advise would be thanks

for example :

i would like make a request like "http:servername/index.aspx" ,

and i'll setup the application which integrate into the FiddlerCore on the server ,

i hope the application can collect incoming request and response

11/5  Finally , I find the answer what i want , the url below

[topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488553/how-use-fiddler-to-check-traffic-of-a-web-service-between-two-web-sites?rq=1)

Comment: Your question is very unclear.

Comment: Fiddler captures all outgoing HTTP requests that use the system proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to run FiddlerCore on the server and collect inbound traffic, you want to use FiddlerCore in Reverse Proxy mode. http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/UseFiddlerAsReverseProxy shows the process for Fiddler itself, but FiddlerCore is similar.

Answer (score 0):

How do you make the request? A localhost? Try with the server/machine name in the URL instead.

Comment: i would like make a request like [http:servername/index.aspx]