# using block swallowing exceptions

Tags: c#, exception, using-statement

I have

```
void foo1()
{
   using(...){...}
}

void foo2()
{
   using(...){...}
}

void foo3()
{
   using(...){...}
}
```

and I have

```
void foo()
{
    ...
    backgroundWorker.DoWork += (s, ev) =>
                                           {
                                               try
                                               {
                                                   foo1();
                                                   foo2();
                                                   foo3();
                                               }
                                               catch (Exception ex)
                                               {
                                                   // log ex
                                               }
                                           };
      ...    
}
```

and I just read  that [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) blocks swallow exceptions. It there an elegant way to handle exceptions from `foo1()`, `foo2()` and  `foo3()` in `foo()`. I *don't* want to have a try/catch inside of each `using` block in the methods. I did stumble into [this post](http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/51/c#-using-blocks-can-swallow-exceptions) where an extension method is suggested but I'm just checking to see if there is anything better.

FYI, Network disconnection causes the logic inside the `using` block to throw an exception and that's what I'm trying to handle in one common place.

Thanks,

Comment: What on earth are you talking about?  Using does not block exceptions.  It interacts with exceptions in the sense that using places an implicit try..finally around the statement block, but using does not kill exceptions raised within the statement block.

Comment: I think your problem is that it's your background worker thread throwing the exception and you don't have anything checking in on that to bubble it up to your main thread. Your `using` block shouldn't have anything to do with it. However, I'm making some assumptions here as well. A `using` block is just syntactic sugar for creating an IDisposable variable, running code, then calling Dispose() on that object at the end if I recall correctly.

Comment: @SethO the msdn page states that the compiler translates `using` to a `try-finally` block where the `finally` block calls `Dispose()` but there is no catch block so any exceptions that may be thrown are lost.

Comment: @TheOtherGuy try/finally without a catch still throws the exception, it just executes finally before throwing it.

Comment: @TheOtherGuy - I apologize; I missed the second link before I commented. I am reading up on this now. Interesting question.

Comment: @Jaxidian but the exception does not bubble up to my catch block (even if it's not in backgroundworker's thread). see the linked post that has an example to prove it http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/51/c#-using-blocks-can-swallow-exceptions

Comment: @TheOtherGuy This still makes sense to me although after reading that post more, my comment about threads is no longer valid. I think of it like this order of events: #1) Instantiate IDisposable #2) Using block throws exception #3) Finally method stops that exception momentarily until it's done but then throws an exception of its own #4) Finally block's exception gets thrown and bubbled up because you said "no matter what, dispose this before you do anything else" and it couldn't do this. For this (and many other) reasons, you need to make sure your Dispose() is very solid/robust code.

Comment: @Jaxidian I'm using a `SqlDataReader` so it's not my own `Dispose()`. I understand the mechanism and it kinda makes sense but I'm just checking to if there is any workaround/alternative that people usually use.

Comment: @TheOtherGuy: What about rolling out the using's into try/finally's?

Comment: @0A0D that would be an option but if I think I'll be better off doing try/catch inside of each `using` to take advantage of `using`'s finally block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I understand the confusion. Here's some pseudo-code (it may actually execute?) explaining your scenario more simply:

```
public class Foo
{
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        using (var x = new Thing())
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("This code breaks");
        }
    }

    private class Thing : IDisposable
    {
        public override Dispose()
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Help, I can't dispose!");
        }
    }
}
```

This code can be thought of as the same as this code:

```
public class Foo
{
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        var x = new Thing();
        try
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("This code breaks");
            x.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            x.Dispose();
            rethrow;
        }
    }

    private class Thing : IDisposable
    {
        public override Dispose()
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Help, I can't dispose!");
        }
    }
}
```

By using a `using` block, you are essentially saying, "No matter what you do, execute `Dispose()` on this object before moving on." However, the `using` block doesn't gracefully handle the case when `Dispose()` fails. Because of this, it never gets around to throwing the inside exception because there was another exception that pre-empted it, even if it occurred afterwards.

Does this make sense? Did I even answer your question? I'm not sure if you're looking for help understanding this or what.

Comment: Does a using block even have a catch? I thought it was just a try/finally.

Comment: Actually I understand what's going on. In my case I'm using `SqlDataReader`'s Dispose() so there is no rethrow or any exception thrown. I'm trying to see if there is a way to detect the failure in the caller.

Comment: @0A0D: No but I was being a bit verbose to emphasize how to expect it to act. When that finally block executes code that in turn throws an exception, well, you don't get all of that finally block's code to execute because an exception is thrown midway through it. This post was not meant to show what code it generates but rather to show how it acts and to emphasize that point.

Comment: @TheOtherGuy: Then I would say the "best" way (easiest to read/maintain code without over-architecting a solution, although this is very much a judgement call and I'm far to ignorant to make that judgement for you) is that you should not use `using` blocks but rather roll your own `try`/`catch`/`finally` blocks so you can more more explicit in how you want it to react (perhaps with `try`/`catch` blocks inside your own `finally` block.

Comment: @TheOtherGuy: You can also stack using statements, which may work in your case.

Comment: I guess I'll skip using `using` in this case then. I was hoping there would be a work-around so I could keep the `using`s but I guess not. Thanks guys!.

Comment: According to [Framework Design Guidelines](http://www.amazon.com/Framework-Design-Guidelines-Conventions-Libraries/dp/0321545613): "**AVOID** throwing an exception from within Dispose(bool) except under critical situations where the containing process has been corrupted." And, since Dispose() should delegate to Dispose(true)...

Answer (score 2):

My fear is that Microsoft went down the same rabbit hole here as they did with WCF.

See [Avoiding Problems with the Using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx).

Maybe they should follow their own [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577607/should-you-implement-idisposable-dispose-so-that-it-never-throws/577671#577671).

In almost every (other) case a `using` block is a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Youcan try this code to bubble-up and exception from a using statement

```
Exception exc = null;
using (var x = new object())
{
    try
    {
       // do something x, that causes an exception to be thrown
    }
    catch(Exception ex) { exc = ex; } // bubble-up the exception
 }
 if(exc != null) { throw exc; } // throw the exception if it is not null
```

Comment: This would work fine, except for the fact that Object doesn't implement IDisposable, and can thus not be used in a using statement, and your rethrowing in this fashion will mess up the stack trace.

Comment: x = new object() ; you can replace new object() with the correct class and parameters.
Also, the stack trace will be intact ... as you can read the stack trace as given by the top-level exception or check the inner exception.  You can even call GetBaseException(), etc.

Comment: I don't see the point of catching an exception in a using statement, only to rethrow it afterwards. Why not refrain from handling it entirely, as the net result will bhe exactly the same?

Comment: No because generally an exception thrown in a using statement is often hidden and that is based on observed behavior.

Comment: Interesting. I've personally never had this happen to me, which is why the rethrow seems useless to me, but if there are situations where Exceptions don't propagate as they should, then, yeah, this may work.