# Convert asynchronous action to asynchronous function delegate, preserving synchronous exception delivery

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task

I want to convert asynchronous action delegates to asynchronous function delegates that return a specified value. I have come up with an extension method for this:

```
public static Func<Task<TResult>> Return<TResult>(this Func<Task> asyncAction, TResult result)
{
    ArgumentValidate.NotNull(asyncAction, nameof(asyncAction));

    return async () =>
    {
        await asyncAction();
        return result;
    };
}
```

However, my extension method is buggy in that exceptions that would have been delivered synchronously from the action delegate now get delivered asynchronously from the function delegate. Concretely:

```
Func<Task> asyncAction = () => { throw new InvalidOperationException(); };
var asyncFunc = asyncAction.Return(42);
var task = asyncFunc();   // exception should be thrown here
await task;               // but instead gets thrown here
```

Is there a way of creating this wrapper in such a way that synchronous exceptions continue to delivered synchronously? Is `ContinueWith` the way to go?

**Update**: A concrete example of an asynchronous operation that throws exceptions synchronously:

```
public static Task WriteAllBytesAsync(string filePath, byte[] bytes)
{
    if (filePath == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(filePath, nameof(filePath));
    if (bytes == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(filePath, nameof(bytes));

    return WriteAllBytesAsyncInner(filePath, bytes);
}

private static async Task WriteAllBytesAsyncInner(string filePath, byte[] bytes)
{
    using (var fileStream = File.OpenWrite(filePath))
        await fileStream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

Test:

```
Func<Task> asyncAction = () => WriteAllBytesAsync(null, null);
var asyncFunc = asyncAction.Return(42);
var task = asyncFunc();   // ArgumentNullException should be thrown here
await task;               // but instead gets thrown here
```

Comment: can you provide a more concrete example?

Comment: It's not clear why you'd expect the exception to be thrown synchronously. If you call `asyncAction()` *that* won't throw an exception either - it will return a faulted task.

Comment: @JonSkeet: You're right; I had a small bug in my example (the anonymous function should not have been marked as `async`). Does the question make sense now?

Comment: @Douglas: Hmm. Only because your `Func<Task>` isn't actually doing *anything* async. Presumably normally it would be code which actually used async/await, and just happened to throw an exception? At that point, again, you'd end up with calling `asyncAction()` not throwing.

Comment: @DanielA.White: For a concrete example of where one would use this, look at the third overload in the last code snippet (under "Update") of [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35613744/1149773).

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes. I have asynchronous operations that throw initial exceptions synchronously (mainly `ArgumentException`), and the remainder asynchronously through the returned `Task`. I want to preserve this behaviour in my `Return` transformation.

Comment: @Douglas: I suspect that if you show an example of how those asynchronous operations are implemented, you'll get an example of what to do in your `Return` method...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you won't be able to use `async` in the initial call. That much is clear. But you can use a synchronous delegate which calls the function, and then captures the returned task to await it inside an async delegate:

```
public static Func<Task<TResult>> Return<TResult>(this Func<Task> asyncAction, TResult result)
{
    ArgumentValidate.NotNull(asyncAction, nameof(asyncAction));

    return () =>
    {
        // Call this synchronously
        var task = asyncAction();
        // Now create an async delegate for the rest
        Func<Task<TResult>> intermediate = async () => 
        {
            await task;
            return result;
        };
        return intermediate();
    };
}
```

Alternatively, refactor it into two methods, basically extracting the asynchronous lambda expression into an async method:

```
public static Func<Task<TResult>> Return<TResult>(
    this Func<Task> asyncAction, TResult result)
{
    ArgumentValidate.NotNull(asyncAction, nameof(asyncAction));

    return () =>
    {
        var task = asyncAction();
        return AwaitAndReturn(task, result);
    };
}

public static async Func<Task<TResult>> AwaitAndReturn<TResult>(
    this Task asyncAction, TResult result)
{
    await task;
    return result;
}
```